# Unable to contact my own XML-RPC server

Tags: roscore

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,

after an upgrade of my Fedora system (now version 14) and a reinstall of ROS I tryed to start roscore but I got following message all the time:

[eos@poseidonius Documents]$ roscore

... logging to /home/eos/.ros/log/41d3b050-4838-11e0-95f3-0024d71f2bbc/roslaunch-poseidonius-13240.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

**Unable to contact my own XML-RPC server, this is a highly unusual error and should be reported immediately.**
My URI is [http://poseidonius:45166/]

Just some variable checks according to other questions found in the internet:

1. echo $ROS_HOST       (empty but set to) poseidonius
2. echo $ROS_IP         (empty but set correct) 192.168.178.31
3. echo $ROS_MASTER_URI (http://localhost:11311 set to) http://poseidonius:11311

What I have to do?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9309/unable-to-contact-my-own-xml-rpc-server/) by [Poseidonius](https://answers.ros.org/users/248/poseidonius/) on ROS Answers with karma: 427 on 2011-03-06

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Poseidonius](https://answers.ros.org/users/248/poseidonius/) on 2011-03-06**:
Hi Eric, yes, you are right. The values in branches are the ROS "default" values on my computer. After some websites I changed them to the second ones ...

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2011-03-06**:
With your "echo $ROS_*", what exactly do you mean by "empty but set..."? Do you set them before running roscore? Do you mean they are empty and the values listed are what you expect? The values listed are the values for your computer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Assuming your IP address is `192.168.178.31`, a quick fix would be to execute the following before attempting to start a `roscore`:

```
export ROS_HOSTNAME=192.168.178.31
export ROS_IP=192.168.178.31
export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://192.168.178.31:11311
```

If that works lets `roscore` startup, then we can work backwards to find the exact problem spot.

Also, if you haven't seen it already, you may also want to take a look at the [Network Setup](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/NetworkSetup) page on the wiki.

As @kwc pointed out in the comments, this configuration will be very sensitive to changes in your current IP address. A more stable configuration for permanent use would be

```
export ROS_HOSTNAME=localhost
export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311
```

However, if your networking configuration is currently in a very bad state, localhost may not resolve to an IP address (or an incorrect IP address). Using bare IP addresses as in the first configuration chunk will get your around any problems in hostname resolution that you may be experiencing and provide a good place to start tracking down your networking issues.

---

Originally posted by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) with karma: 8406 on 2011-03-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) on 2011-03-06**:
In order to have a more stable configuration, I would probably try ROS_HOSTNAME=localhost, ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311  . FYI: there is no need to set both ROS_HOSTNAME and ROS_IP.  Just one is fine.

**Comment by [Poseidonius](https://answers.ros.org/users/248/poseidonius/) on 2011-03-06**:
I make some experiments, something seems to be wrong with my network configuration ... I will find the fault. Thanks again

**Comment by [Poseidonius](https://answers.ros.org/users/248/poseidonius/) on 2011-03-06**:
Hi Eric, thanks for your help and patient ... using your suggested configuration it works fine !